# Spring Data Rest handling AfterLinkSaveEvent

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

Let's say there are two simple entities:

```
@Entity
public class Author {
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Book> books;

@Entity
public class Book {
    private String title;
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Author> authors;
```

Next I am sending a `PATCH` request to update the Author:

```
http://localhost:8080/authors/1
body:
{
    "books": [
        "http://localhost:8080/books/2",
        "http://localhost:8080/books/3"
    ]
}
```

There is a handler:

```
@RepositoryEventHandler
public class AuthorEventHandler {
    @HandleBeforeSave
    public void handleBeforeAuthorSave(Author author) {
        System.out.println("handleBeforeSave Author: " + author);
    }

    @HandleAfterSave
    public void handleAfterAuthorSave(Author author) {
        System.out.println("HandleAfterSave Author: " + author);
    }

    @HandleBeforeLinkSave
    public void handleBeforeLinks(Author author, List<Book> books) {
        System.out.println("handleBeforeLinks Author: " + author);
    }

    @HandleAfterLinkSave
    public void handleAfterLinks(Author author, List<Book> books) {
        System.out.println("handleAfterLinks Author: " + author);
    }
}
```

The handler catches only the `AfterSaveEvent` and `BeforeSaveEvent`.
Spring does not produce `Before-AfterLinkSave` events.

**EDIT**:
I've noticed the method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = BASE_MAPPING, method = { PATCH, PUT, POST }
createPropertyReference()
```

With the `BASE_MAPPING = "/{repository}/{id}/{property}";`
So the PATCH request on the `http://localhost:8080/authors/1/books` triggers it. It's not the way I thought about from the start.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed Spring Data Rest doesn't produce `Before-AfterLinkSave` events; it's only either `Before` or `After`.

Of course without knowing what particular problem you are trying to solve it's hard to tell but if you need to handle `Before-After = Aroud` execution then you might want to look at [**Spring AOP**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html) using which you can create a *Pointcut* to repository save method and set up an *Advice* (basically interceptor) arond that method execution.

> An advice is an action taken by an aspect at a particular Joinpoint.
> Different types of advice include “around,” “before” and “after”
> advice.

Comment: I was trying to resolve 2 problems: first I expected to fire the `LinkEvents` on `/{repository}/{id}` instead of the `/{repository}/{id}/{property}` (but it is not possible).
The second - adding transactional support on events. This https://stackoverflow.com/a/53236152/4207793 helped me to do it.

Comment: Great! So AOP was the way to go in the end. Glad you solved your problem. Good point abt transactional support, events are reaaly not supporting that connection to the method execution.

Comment: Yes. Then only one difference that I've included only the two classes `webmvc.RepositoryEntityController` and `webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController` instead of the whole `data.rest.webmvc` package. (It would work in both cases)